# SQL Server connection to Laravel

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-8

I'm trying to establish a connection to SQL Server with my Laravel app **locally** .

What I've done is checking pdo files are installed correctly
and phpinfo shows sqlsrv.

ENV Connection String

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DB_HOST=DESKTOP-Q6F14ID
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=MYDB
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I've set the default to sqlsrv

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
```

And still get the error

> SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
> (SQL: select * from sys.sysobjects where id = object_id(migrations) and xtype in ('U', 'V'))

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException
> ..
> PDO::__construct("sqlsrv:Server=DESKTOP-Q6F14ID,1433;Database=MYDB", "", "", [])

I've tried windows auth to connect but it didn't work.
I've tried this string too.

```
DB_DATABASE=MYDB
DB_USERNAME=DESKTOP-Q6F14ID\MyUsername
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I've tried these host names too

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_HOST=MyLocalIP
DB_HOST=DESKTOP-Q6F14ID
```

And tried these usernames too without passwords

```
DB_USERNAME=DESKTOP-Q6F14ID
DB_USERNAME=DESKTOP-Q6F14ID/MyUsername
DB_USERNAME=MyUsername
```

and tried SQL Server authentication instead of windows and I created a user in SQL Server and ii can't even login.

```
DB_USERNAME=Laravel
DB_PASSWORD=admin123
```

I've added a rule in the firewall to enable 1433 port
still nothing.

And I've checked the port in SQL config that is using 1433 correctly.

Comment: Goto SQL Server Configuration and turn on Shared Memory, also enable Remote Connections

Comment: After you checked (and fixed?) the Server Protocols configuration in SQL Server Configuration Manager did you restart the SQL Server service? It needs a restart for any changes here to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

Check the config files name (database.php) and scroll down check to find sqlsrv and .env files add  DATABASE_URL=

database this one miss it

```
 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'sqlsrv'),
```

this miss its on  evn DATABASE_URL=

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlsrv
DATABASE_URL=
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=1433
DB_DATABASE=DBNAME
DB_USERNAME=
DB_PASSWORD=
```

```
'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
        ],
```

try restart  php service

systemctl restart php7.0-fpm.service

Comment: The setup was correct only its sql server side i had to enable TCP/IP from sql server config

Answer (score 0):

After Enabling shared memory and remote connection,
It turns out the only thing was missing is to enable TCP/IP In sql server config and it solved the problem immediatly